What are the limits of room randomization in Hades 2?
In Hades 2, having used most of my Changes of Fate in Tartarus rooms during one run, it seems that there's a limit to how many Boons rooms / Trial rooms can appear?
And the "NPC Chambers" can only occur once per biome.
What are the limits for the other room rewards? I tried to get a Boon to appear after a Trial in Tartarus, but only had options of Poms, Food or Money, after like 5-6 rerolls? Was I just unlucky or I hit my maximum number of boon rooms or something else?
I know from looking at the code that Chaos Gates can only appear every 4 rooms unless Sparks of Ixion are bought, but that's not a room reward.
And I've heard that there can only be two Daedelus Hammers and the Final Shop's Anvil in a run, but not sure how Hammers are counted. I guess that a Shop hammer and a reward hammer count the same?
